# Being made vs made

Tags: participles

I found these examples below, but I cannot understand why the one has the auxiliary verb "be" and the other does not. When should I use the verb "be" to form participial constructions?

1. Made from the softest leather imaginable, they are as comfortable as
   a pair of slippers. (they are made from the softest leather imaginable)
2. Being made so welcome at the hotel, I was reluctant to leave. (I was made so welcome)

Comment: When your participle is formed not by a simple fomula **past participle of a main verb**, that is, if it consists not from just of one verb in its V3 form, it cannot be called **past participle** at all. That is, "being made" isn't an example of past participle, it is an example of participial construction, that was formed using a formula "being + past participle form of a main verb *make*". So you **never** can use any auxillary verbs to form **past participle**, but you **must** use them to form various **participial constructions**.

Answer (score 2):

The difference depends on two different senses of the verb *to make.*

*Made from leather* is a quality of the shoes - what they are constructed of. Before they were made, they didn't exist.

*Being made welcome* is something that happened to the hotel guest. When they arrived, they were made (caused) to feel welcome.

Answer (score 0):

“to make” is active, and “to be made” is passive.

As with active/passive in general, the meaning is roughly the same but the actor is different—often unspecified in the passive form. It is a stylistic choice.